# Does anyone know how i can group this dataframe by month?

Tags: python

Im looking to group this dataframe by month and then find the month with the most accidents, any idea how i would do this?

Tried a few things using the group_by function but think i need to sort the dates into months first

small part of dataframe;

```
   Accidents    Longitude   Latitude    Date        Day_of_Week  Time   
0   124         -0.153842   51.508057   18/02/2019        2     17:50   
1   234         -0.127949   51.436208   15/02/2019        3     21:45   
2   222         -0.124193   51.526795   01/03/2019        3     01:50   
3   188         -0.191044   51.546387   01/07/2019        3     01:20   
4   300         -0.200064   51.541121   01/11/2019        3     00:40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to extract the `month` from your `Date` column, there are various ways to do that but if you consider it as string, you can do it by:

```
df["month"] = df.Date.apply(lambda s: int(s.split("/")[1]))

   Accidents  Longitude   Latitude        Date  Day_of_Week   Time  month
0        124  -0.153842  51.508057  18/02/2019            2  17:50      2
1        234  -0.127949  51.436208  15/02/2019            3  21:45      2
2        222  -0.124193  51.526795  01/03/2019            3  01:50      3
3        188  -0.191044  51.546387  01/07/2019            3  01:20      7
4        300  -0.200064  51.541121  01/11/2019            3  00:40     11
```

Then you can use that column for `groupby` and aggregation:

```
df.groupby("month").sum()[["Accidents"]].sort_values("Accidents", ascending=False)

       Accidents
month
2            358
11           300
3            222
7            188
```

Comment: Brilliant that works. Also, now ignoring the accident column is there anyway to count the number of rows in this by month; df["month"] = df.Date.apply(lambda s: int(s.split("/")[1]))

Comment: Instead of using `sum`, you can use `count` to get the count of rows within each group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Accidents'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
df.groupby(df.Date.str.split("/", expand=True)[1]).Accidents.sum()
```